# Compile list of all ACLs for an entire drive

Tags: powershell, acl

I would like to generate a list of access details for all folders and files on a specifc drive (F:) and export to a .csv. I am fairly certain this can be completed using Powershell but I have no idea how. Please help!

Comment: `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Acl`, `Select-Object`, and `Export-Csv`.  Possibly `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: a CSV file is a poor storage medium for what you're asking for because you have an array of objects (files and folders) and each of those will have an array of permissions, so your whole thing is 3 dimensional and not well suited to a 2d storage medium like CSV. XML would be a better way, or a database I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) and pass the `/Save` and `/t` parameters to reclusively go through the passed in path and save the results to a file.

```
icacls F:\ /Save allAcls.txt /t
```

Here is a example output

```
D:(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICIIOID;GXGR;;;BU)
COM_HISTORY
D:(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICIIOID;GXGR;;;BU)
Documents
D:(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICIIOID;GXGR;;;BU)
COM_HISTORY\server.metadata
D:(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)
```

- The first line is blank because it represents the name of the root of the drive
- The 3rd and 5th lines are the folders `F:\COM_HISTORY` and `F:\Documents`
- The 7th line is a file located at `F:\COM_HISTORY\server.metadata`
- The 2nd, 4th, 6th, and 8th lines are the ACLs for the previous line's file or folder.